# How to check an alternative of a token in ANTLR's visitor mode?

Tags: java, compilation, antlr

I want to build a simple rule engine using ANTLR's visitor mode, but when it comes with alternative tokens, I get confused how to get which alternative is. Can anyone help me with that?(sorry of my poor English)

```
grammar RuleExpression;
expression: '(' Operator arg* ')';
arg: STRING|INTEGER|BOOLEAN|expression;
STRING: '"' .+ '"';
INTEGER: [0-9]+;
BOOLEAN: 'true'|'false';
Operator: [a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

How do know an arg is a STRING or INTEGER or BOOLEAN or expression?

Comment: You should be receiving an instance of `ArgContext` (or something like that), isn't it? It should be having methods named `STRING()`, `INTEGER()`, etc. after your token definition names. You can check which one has value in it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have searched this answer, but it is a bit of tedious to use. Is there some method which I can use switch statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] Is there some method which I can use switch statement?

You can inspect the context's `start` token type:

```java
@Override
public Object visitArg(RuleExpressionParser.ArgContext ctx) {
  switch (ctx.start.getType()) {
    case RuleExpressionLexer.STRING:
      return ...;
    case RuleExpressionLexer.INTEGER:
      return ...;
    case RuleExpressionLexer.BOOLEAN:
      return ...;
    default:
      // It was an `expression`
      return super.visitExpression(ctx.expression());
  }
}
```

Or you could [label](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) the `arg` alternatives:

```
arg
 : STRING     #StringArg
 | INTEGER    #IntegerArg
 | BOOLEAN    #BooleanArg
 | expression #ExpressionArg
 ;
```

which will cause the visitor to have the following methods:

```java
@Override 
public T visitStringArg(RuleExpressionParser.StringArgContext ctx) ...

@Override 
public T visitIntegerArg(RuleExpressionParser.IntegerArgContext ctx) ...

@Override 
public T visitBooleanArg(RuleExpressionParser.BooleanArgContext ctx) ...

@Override 
public T visitExpressionArg(RuleExpressionParser.ExpressionArgContext ctx) ...
```

instead of the single `T visitArg(RuleExpressionParser.ArgContext ctx)` method.